# New column with in a Pandas Dataframe with respect to duplicates in given column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Hi i have a dataframe with a column "id" like below

```
   
id    
abc
def
ghi
abc
abc
xyz
def
```

I need a new column "id1" with a number 1 appended to it and number should be incremented for every duplicate. output should be like below.

```
id    id1
abc   abc1
def   def1
ghi   ghi1
abc   abc2
abc   abc3
xyz   xyz1
def   def2
```

Can anyone suggest me a solution for this?

Comment: Can you show the code where you have tried something?

Comment: @HarvIpan, i have no idea on how to proceed with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`groupby.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for count `id`s, add `1` and convert to `string`s:

```
df['id1'] = df['id'] + df.groupby('id').cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
print (df)
    id   id1
0  abc  abc1
1  def  def1
2  ghi  ghi1
3  abc  abc2
4  abc  abc3
5  xyz  xyz1
6  def  def2
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.groupby('id').cumcount())
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    2
5    0
6    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: The OP wants `id` to be `id1`.